# Need help with a Binomial Distribution question

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

**The Question with the answer:**

[image]

This is a Binomial Distribution question and I don't know how they got the (0.5)????, the one I marked on red.
It's not mentioned in the question that's why I'm confused :/

please help and thanks in advance <3

Comment: When nothing is given, you are required to use your intuition in assigning probabilities. Since it is given in the question that the coin is *fair*, you can safely assume that the outcomes are equally likely.

Comment: I didn't know that so thank you so much for the comment, it's really really realllllly helpful! I Appreciate your help <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac12$ is the probability of getting heads in *one* throw of a fair coin.

This is the $p$ parameter to the binomial distribution.

Comment: Now I get it finally!!! Thank you sooooo much <3 a true life saver!